# How can I use Meteor to build different UI for mobile apps and web browsers

Tags: cordova, meteor

I have a project that requires a Bootstrap responsive web browser app, and a mobile app (with ionic components).
How can i achieve this with Meteor? Can I use the same code base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. In [TyPhone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idimbn19udlnf6trycde) we are combining Ionic for mobile and Semantic-UI for web. You could easily do the same with Bootstrap.

[TyPhone is open source](https://github.com/chfritz/typhone), so feel free to check it out, but the essential idea is to just let iron-router send different templates.

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    if (Meteor.isCordova) {
        this.layout('layout');
        this.render('mobile');
    } else {
        this.render('web');
    }
});
```

You may still need to make sure that the CSS files do not step onto each others feet, but this is a good way to get started.

---

**Edit**:

One issue I ran into was that ionic makes the body unscrollable, so I needed to overwrite the `overflow` property of the body on the web version. This is how I did that:

JS:

```js
Template.web.onRendered(function() {
    $("body").addClass("web");
});
```

CSS:

```css
body.web {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that's simple and smart. Did you use any particular approach to deal with the CSS conflicts, if any? Great app, BTW!

Comment: That's the only part that is kind of ugly. I wish iron-router would allow you to server different css files or different heads with each route, but as I know it doesn't. So instead you may need to resolve conflicts yourself. I added one example I ran into to the answer above (regarding `overflow`).

Comment: Hello again! I think a have a good solution to the CSS conflicts. If you are using LESS or Sass , you can do something like .web{@import bootstrap.scss}